# Dialogflow fulfilment webhook url support self signed certificates?

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, webhooks, dialogflow-es, self-signed

I am using Dialogflow fulfilment webhook for weather.

Dialogflow says "You can use only https:// in fulfillment url when "Google Assistant" integration enabled"

so, I tried Self-Signed certificates for https url. 
but I can't get webhook response.

I can't use Self-Signed certificates for webhook url?

thank you for anyhelp!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself after I have tried for 7 days.

Dialogflow fulfilment webhook url doesn't support self signed certificates.

so, I used heroku and aws lambda.

they support https and worked fine with Dialogflow webhook.

I hope it will be helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several times to use Self-Signed certificates but I was not able to do it. I  had to get a "SSL DV Standard" and the webhook started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you gived up about using SSL here is how to remove Google Assistant integration and use http webhook :

1. Export your DialogFlow bot :

[image: export]

2. Delete the bot:

[image]

3. Create a new empty bot and set a http webhook :

[image]

4. Import your previously exported bot :

[image]

5. Now you should have your previous bot working & released from Google Assistant

Answer (score 0):

The self signed certificate is not supported ,instead you could use ngrok to convert http://localhost:8080 to https. Link is here https://ngrok.com/download

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to get an HTTPS link, if you don't want to deploy the product in a global server yet, you can use libraries like Localtunnel and Ngrok which generate a safe HTTPS link of the localhost ports for some hours( useful for POCs, demos, testing)