# Google action fulfillment url (with my own java server)

Tags: java, google-home

I'm trying to play with Google Home Action. I've created a new project, give it a name, then have to put a fulfillment url.

I've already implemented a small server (in Java, by using the class HttpsServer) to control a connected object in my house (it's already worked, I can send action to it by invoking a url, when I'm connected from my WIFI or outside of my home network with my 4G smartphone). The url is something like https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/my_object?action=test

So I've just tried to add a new "google" context to my server to do some "google action" when invoking via url https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/google. For now with this url, I just reply with a "OK google" string in a 200 answer and also display it locally on my console output. When invoking myself, it just display the string (by invoking it from my 4G connection).

Naively I think I just have to put my https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/google inside the fulfillment input box into the Google Action... and bim I will just have to understand the requests sent by Google (manage authentication, etc) to my tiny server. But when trying to invoke it via the simulator, my server is not triggered.

I must have missed something, but what?

If someone can help me, or put me to the correct direction, it would be great.

Regards

Comment: Hmm maybe my problem is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50967166/dialogflow-fulfilment-webhook-url-support-self-signed-certificates  I have to test it!

Comment: I've tested using ngrok; (I test, I can access to my java server via an oustide network, example 4G smartphone, thanks to ngrok tunel), but google still do not send any request to my url (even ngrok do not log anything when test, via the google simulator, my action)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to resume:

Google Home Action accept only HTTPS fulfilement url.
And the https server must not use a self signed certificate.
Even with that, it never triger anything to my personal server (I've written to Google Support, answer me that tey will look... but after 1 week, problem is not solved).

My solution:

I just create an account on IFTTT, associate it to my google home account, and create a simple "applet" with if (select google assistant, input sentence I have to say), then (select webook, put the url of my server with the correct parameter in it)... save... it publish it to my google home assistant (how? I don't know and don't care)... try.. it works!

Don't know why Google do not provide something as simple as IFTTT to work with their assistant.